# overriden method "disappear" in the razor file

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I am using Visual Studio 2019 w/ the latest build.

In the .razor file, I added @code{}.

When I tried to insert the first overridden method, like OnInitialized(), Visual Studio immediately deletes/condense it.  When I tried to re-create it, the method is not available to be overridden.

Does anyone have this problem or does everyone have the code in the .cs file?

Thanks!

Comment: Code samples and _exact_ error messages would be helpful. I have no idea what "deletes/condense it" means.

Comment: @Henk...it's hard to show w/ code sample, because it's Visual Studio behavior.  If you follow my steps in the description, you may or may not be able to reproduce it.  I am looking for folks who experienced the same behavior and how they "fix" it

Comment: Your 'steps' are not very clear or complete. Why did you add an `@code{}`?  What was wrong with the one that's already there?

Comment: I usually have problems with overriding methods in blazor components found in intellisense; when I press enter to override selected method some code usually disappears rather than gets added. So I need to type the override manually instead. I believe it's a vs bug.

Comment: @olabacker  Thank you!  I just opened a case with Microsoft...if you are interested in following the case, it's here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/override-in/1317314

Comment: Try to update vs2019 to version 16.8.4.

Comment: @M.Hassan...thanks for reply...I am at 16.8.4.  :)